# Failed on using Swift to implement in-app email

Tags: ios, swift, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to use swift to implement in-app email. When I click the button, the email window pops up. However, I am unable to send my email. Moreover, after I click cancel-delete draft, I cannot go back to the original screen.

```
import UIkit
import MessageUI


class Information : UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{

    var myMail: MFMailComposeViewController!

    @IBAction func sendReport(sender : AnyObject) {

        if(MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()){
            myMail = MFMailComposeViewController()

            //myMail.mailComposeDelegate

            // set the subject
            myMail.setSubject("My report")

            //To recipients
            var toRecipients = ["lipeilin@gatech.edu"]
            myMail.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

            //CC recipients
            var ccRecipients = ["tzhang85@gatech.edu"]
            myMail.setCcRecipients(ccRecipients)

            //CC recipients
            var bccRecipients = ["tzhang85@gatech.edu"]
            myMail.setBccRecipients(ccRecipients)

            //Add some text to the message body
            var sentfrom = "Email sent from my app"
            myMail.setMessageBody(sentfrom, isHTML: true)

            //Include an attachment
            var image = UIImage(named: "Gimme.png")
            var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

            myMail.addAttachmentData(imageData, mimeType: "image/jped", fileName:     "image")

            //Display the view controller
            self.presentViewController(myMail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your device cannot send emails", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    }




func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!,
    didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult,
    error: NSError!){

        switch(result.value){
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Email sent")

        default:
            println("Whoops")
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: You never set the `mailComposeDelegate`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you haven't set the current view controller as the `mailComposeDelegate` of `myMail`, the `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult` method isn't being called.  After you init `myMail`, make sure to add:

```
myMail.mailComposeDelegate = self
```

and you'll be good to go

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! However, after I click "send", it seems that the email is not sent. Could I ask how to send my email?

Comment: Are you doing this on the device or the simulator?

Comment: Oh I realize that I am doing this on the simulator...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for a non MFMailCompose option, here's what I did to send using Gmail's SMTP servers.

1. Download a zip of this repo: https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage
2. Drag and drop the files under SMTPLibrary into your XCode project
3. Create a new header file - `MyApp-Briding-Header.h`
4. Replace new header file with this:

> ```
> #import "Base64Transcoder.h"
> #import "HSK_CFUtilities.h"
> #import "NSData+Base64Additions.h"
> #import "NSStream+SKPSMTPExtensions.h"
> #import "SKPSMTPMessage.h"
> ```

5. Go to Project(Targets > MyApp on the left)/Build Settings/Swift Compiler - Code Generation
6. Add path to header file under `Objective-C Briding Header` -> `Debug` (i.e. `MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h`
7. Go to Project/Build Phases/Compile Sources
8. Select all .m files and click enter. Type `-fno-objc-arc` and hit enter.
9. Use this code to send email:

> ```
> var mail = SKPSMTPMessage()       
> mail.fromEmail = "fromemail@gmail.com"
> mail.toEmail = "tomail@gmail.com"
> mail.requiresAuth = true
> mail.login = "fromemail@gmail.com"
> mail.pass = "password"
> mail.subject = "test subject"
> mail.wantsSecure = true
> mail.relayHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
>
> mail.relayPorts = [587]
>
> var parts: NSDictionary = [
>             "kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
>             "kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey": "test message",
> ]
>
> mail.parts = [parts]
>
> mail.send()
> ```

Hope it helps someone. I didn't want to use the MFMailCompose option because I didn't want to have to prompt the user.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I have composed my email with attached PDF file** document.

Just to test this example you need to drag and drop a sample PDF named "All_about_tax.pdf"

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: UIButton)
    {
        //Check to see the device can send email.
        if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() )
        {
            print("Can send email.")

            let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

            //Set to recipients
            mailComposer.setToRecipients(["your email id here"])

            //Set the subject
            mailComposer.setSubject("Tax info document pdf")

            //set mail body
            mailComposer.setMessageBody("This is what they sound like.", isHTML: true)

            if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("All_about_tax", ofType: "pdf")
            {
                print("File path loaded.")

                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                {
                    print("File data loaded.")
                    mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "All_about_tax.pdf")

                }
            }

            //this will compose and present mail to user
            self.presentViewController(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            print("email is not supported")
        }
    }



    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?)
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```